# how to get returned value from npm-scripts?

Tags: node.js, shell, npm-scripts

In package.json, I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "foo": "echo foo",
    "bar": "npm run foo > result.txt"
}
```

and then if I run `npm run bar`, I will get the text in `result.txt`:

```
> kaze@0.0.55 foo D:\code\kaze
> echo foo

foo
```

That is not what I expected. What I expected is just:

```
foo
```

So, what is the problem with my npm scripts?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `>`, all stdout of its left command execution would be written to `result.txt`, including descriptive information shown in the question. It has nothing to do with `npm run bar`.

If you just run `npm run foo > result.txt` in command line window, same result would be retrieved.

To only include `foo` in `result.txt`, npm option `--silent` can be used:

```
  "scripts": {
    "foo": "echo foo",
    "bar": "npm run foo --silent > result.txt"
  },
```